# Unable to evaluate the Limit of an expression at Infinity, with assumptions on parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions, series-expansion

I need some help in evaluating the following limit with assumptions:

```
Limit[Result, L -> Infinity, Assumptions -> A ∈ Integers && A > 0 && 
    B ∈ Integers && B > 0 && C ∈ Integers && C > 0 && D > 0 && F > 0]
```

where

```
Result := C D (B F)^(A + L) (-C D + B F)^-A 
     ((C D + B F)^(-1 - L) - ((-C D + B F)^(-1 - L)
     Gamma[1 + A + L] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + L, 1 + A + L, 
     2 + L, -((C D + B F)/(-C D + B F))])/(Gamma[A] Gamma[2 + L]))
```

It should come out to **0**, and I am sure of this. I just need to verify.

The reason is that I plugged in values for all of the parameters (except **L**), and then summed over Result from **L=0** to **L=100000** - the sum converges to **1.**

**Mathematica is unable to evaluate this limit as I defined it. Is there a proper way?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you type this correctly? When I simplify this I get `C D (B F)^(A+L) (-C D+B F)^-A`. 
BTW, `D` is a predefined keyword for derivative. You may use some other variable.

Comment: I think I did type correctly... what did you simplify to get that !?

Comment: I just used Simplify[Result].

Comment: Strange. I did not get that. I have version 10.4.

Comment: I noticed that in the code you have posted, there is a new line in the `Result`. This is the reason why it gives different results.

Comment: these suggest +-infinity should be possible results: `Result /. {A -> 3, B -> 2, C -> 5, D -> 7, F -> 11}
Result /. {A -> 3, B -> 2, C -> 5, D -> 7, F -> 29}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to replace `C` by `a B F/D`, where `a > 0`.  Also, specify that `L` is positive.

```
Simplify[Result /. C -> a B F/D, B > 0 && F > 0 && a > 0 && L > 0]
(* (1 - a)^-A a B F (B F)^L (((1 + a) B F)^(-1 - L) - ((-(-1 + a) B F)^(-1 - L)
   Gamma[1 + A + L] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + L, 1 + A + L, 2 + L, 
   (1 + a)/(-1 + a)])/(Gamma[A] Gamma[2 + L])) *)
```

It is not uncommon for `Limit` to fail when dealing with hypergeometric functions.  So, use `Series` instead.

```
Series[%, {L, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> B > 0 && F > 0 && L > 0] // Normal
(* ((1 - a)^-A a (B F)^L ((1 + a) B F)^-L)/(1 + a) *)
FullSimplify[%, B > 0 && F > 0 && L > 0 && a > 0]
(* (1 - a)^-A a (1 + a)^(-1 - L) *)
Limit[%, L -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* 0 *)
```

as desired.

Comment: This is simply brilliant. My next step was to compute the series anyway!